# Fusion chart error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, fusioncharts

i make a fusionchart who give me these two errors?how i remove these errors?i make a fusionchart who give me these two errors?how i remove these errors?

```
<?php

include("DBConn.php");
include("FusionCharts.php");
$link = connectToDB();
$strQuery="select Distinct DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%c-%d-%Y') as transaction_date,sum(amount)as Amount from transactions group by       DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%c-%d-%Y')";
    $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($result) {
$strXML = "<chart caption='Reports' showValues='0' useRoundEdges='1' palette='3'>";
    while($ors = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //Generate <set label='..' value='..' />
    $strXML .= "<set label='" .$ors['transaction_date'] ."' value='" . $ors['Amount'] ."' />";
    }
}
    //free the result set
    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($link);
    //Finally, close <chart> element
    $strXML .= "</chart>";
    //date_default_timezone_set($_SESSION['timezone']);
 ?>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="Charts/FusionCharts.js"></script>
 <div id="chartContainer">
 <?php
 FC_SetRenderer('javascript');
 echo renderChart('Charts/Column2D.swf', // Path to chart type
                '', // Empty string when using Data String Method
                $strXML, // Variable that contains XML string
                'Tracking', // Unique chart ID
                '660', '400', // Width and height in pixels
                false,      // Disable debug mode
                true// Enable 'Register with JavaScript' (Recommended)
            );
 ?>
 </div>
```

and here is errors:

ReferenceError:

```
Prototype is not defined
if(Prototype.Browser.IE)
```

and

ReferenceError:

```
FusionCharts is not defined


...Charts("Tracking") && FusionCharts("Tracking").dispose ) FusionCharts("Tracking"...
```

here is my xml

```
<chart caption='Reports' showValues='0' useRoundEdges='1' palette='3'>
   <set label='1-06-2014' value='50' />
   <set label='1-07-2014' value='151.1500015258789' />
   <set label='1-08-2014' value='45' />
   <set label='1-09-2014' value='0' />
   <set label='1-10-2014' value='0' />
   <set label='1-13-2014' value='0' />
   <set label='1-14-2014' value='0' />
</chart>
```

how to remove these errors?

Comment: how to remove these error give me suggestions plz

Comment: anyone who give me suggestions urgently

Comment: That simply means FusionCharts instance was not initialized. Is it possible to paste your complete php and sql(db schema for the table) code for me to further diagnose the problem?

Comment: Check if you've copied FusionCharts.js in the path specified in your page. To render a JavaScript chart, please ensure, FusionCharts.HC.js, FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js and jquery.min.js. are present in the same folder as FusionCharts.js.Explicit loading of these files are not required.